my paddle is not responding towards keys, Why?
i am building a pong game using python and my paddle is not responding towards keys. Why?
It's showing error
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'int'
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width= 800, height= 600)
screen.title("Pong Game")
screen.tracer(0)

paddle = Turtle()
paddle.shape("square")
paddle.color("white")
paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid = 5, stretch_len = 1)
paddle.penup()
paddle.goto(350, 0)

def go_up():
    new_y= paddle.ycor()+ 20
    paddle.goto(paddle.xcor, new_y)

def go_down():
    new_y= paddle.ycor()- 20
    paddle.goto(paddle.xcor, new_y)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(go_up, "Up")
screen.onkey(go_down, "Down")

When i am pressing up key my paddle should go up but not going.

You need to actually call paddle.xcor() (just like you did with ycor() on the preceding line) to retrieve the current coordinate.  You're missing the () in two places.

"not responding towards keys"? Do you mean "to keys"?
